# Matlab how to add values in the x-axis of a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, scatter

[image: Plot image]

**Plot using `set(gca, 'XTick', [1 10 20 50 100])**

[image: Plot with set(gca,'XTick',[1 10 20 50 100])]

Hi everyone! 
I have created a graph with the function scatter and in the x-axis there are only three values shown: [1 10 100].
I'd like to add some values, specifically I'd like to show [1 5 10 20 50 100]. 
How can i do this?

My code is:

```
line(contrast2*100, RNorm2,'color','black');
hold on
scatter (contrast2*100, RNorm2,'y','filled');
set(gca,'XScale','log')
set(gca,'XTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'XTick').'))
set(gca,'XTick',[1 10 20 50 100])
set(gca,'YScale','log')
set(gca,'YTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'YTick').'))
grid on
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Googling your title yields http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html as the first result. HTH.

Comment: Yes I tried with set(gca,'XTick',[1 10 20 50 100]) but it doesn't work in my graph :/

Comment: @Inis can you include that line in your above example so we can see why it maybe didn't work?

Comment: @Suever I just include it and i have added also another image with the result :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set your `XTick` values *before* you set your `XTickLabels` since you are constructing your `XTickLabels` from the values of the `XTicks` themselves.

What is currently happening is that you have 5 `XTick` values and only 3 labels. Because of this, MATLAB will repeat the labels that you have to populate labels for all `XTick` locations.

```
line(contrast2*100, RNorm2,'color','black');
hold on
scatter (contrast2*100, RNorm2,'y','filled');
set(gca,'XScale','log')
set(gca,'XTick',[1 10 20 50 100])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'XTick').'))
set(gca,'YScale','log')
set(gca,'YTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'YTick').'))
grid on
```

Better yet, there is no real reason for you to be setting `XTickLabel` manually here. If you change the `XTick` locations, the labels will automatically be updated to reflect the new locations.

```
line(contrast2*100, RNorm2,'color','black');
hold on
scatter (contrast2*100, RNorm2,'y','filled');
set(gca, 'XScale', 'log', ...
         'XTick', [1 10 20 50 100], ...
         'YScale', 'log')
```